# Java Structure that is able to determine approximate number of elements less then x in an ordered set which is updated concurrently

Tags: java

Suppose *U* is an ordered set of elements, *S* ⊆*U*, and *x*   ∈ *U*.  ***S* is being updated concurrently**.   I want to get an estimate of the number of elements in *S* that is less *x* in O(log(|*S*|) time.

*S* is being maintained by another software component that I cannot change. However, whenever *e* is inserted (or deleted) into *S* I get a message `e inserted (deleted)`.  I don't want to maintain my own version of *S* since memory is limited.  I am looking for a structure, *ES*, (perhaps using O(log(|S|) space) where I can get a reasonable estimate of the number of elements less than any give *x*. Assume that the entire set *S* can periodically be sampled to recreate or update *ES*.

Update:  I think that this problem statement must include more specific values for *U*.  One obvious case is where *U* are numbers (int, double,etc). Another case is where *U* are strings ordered lexigraphically.

In the case of numbers one could use a probability distribution (but how can that be determined?).

I am wondering if the set *S* can be scanned periodically.  Place the entire set into an array and sort.  Then pick the log(n) values at n/log(n), 2n/log(n) ... n where n = |*S*|.   Then draw a histogram based on those values?

More generally how can one find the appropriate probability distribution from *S*?

Not sure what the unit of measure would be for strings lexigraphically ordered?

Answer (score 1):

By *concurrently*, I'm assuming you mean thread-safe. In that case, I believe what you're looking for is a [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html), which is essentially a concurrent `TreeSet`.  You can use `ConcurrentSkipListSet#headSet.size()` or `ConcurrentSkipListSet#tailSet.size()` to get the amount of elements greater/less than (or equal to) a single element where you can pass in a custom `Comparator`.

Comment: This would not work because the cost  of the size operation is O(|S|) not O(log(|S|). This can be seen in the case where everything is S is less then x.

Answer (score 1):

Is *x* constant? If so it seems easy to track the number less than `x` as they are inserted and deleted?

If *x* isn't constant you could still take a histogram approach. Divide up the range that values can take. As items are inserted / deleted, keep track of how many items are in each range bucket. When you get a query, sum up all the values from smaller buckets.

I accept your point that bucketing is tricky - especially if you know nothing about the underlying data. You could record the first 100 values of *x*, and use those calculate a mean and a standard deviation. Then you could assume the values are normally distributed and calculate the buckets that way.

Obviously if you know more about the underlying data you can use a different distribution model. It would be easy enough to have a modular approach if you want it to be generic.

Comment: No x is not constant.  I like a histogram like approach, but dividing up the range of values is not so simple without sampling the set at some time. For example imagine that the set are integers. What would you set as the maximum and mininum values?  In the more general case here I am talking about objects, not integers, so which objects would you pick for the intevals?

Comment: You could model the buckets statistically based on the first ~100 values you see? I've updated my answer to include this idea.

Comment: How does one calculate a mean and a standard deviation when the elements are not integers and there is no notion of distance?

Comment: I think this only works if your data has a meaningful unit-of-measure. I'm struggling to imagine a use case where there's no unit and yet you wish to count how many are below *x*. I think it would help if you provide more specific details?

Comment: Yes I think your comment is correct a unit-of-measure is required.   I updated my question.